# How to translate into Vietnamese in another language in liferay 7.3.7

Tags: java, liferay

i am using liferay 7.3.7 version, i have a problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhpPW.png)
i want to translate word "My Submissions" from english language to vietnamese language, i have found language module **portal-workflow-lang** and language key is **javax.portlet.title.com_liferay_portal_workflow_web_internal_portlet_UserWorkflowPortlet** that is key of word "My Submissions".
i created a service-wrapper PortalWorkflowLang and write command to .bnd file to override old language module:

```
Bundle-Name: PortalWorkflowLang
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang.over
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0

Provide-Capability:\
liferay.resource.bundle;resource.bundle.base.name="content.Language",\
liferay.resource.bundle;resource.bundle.aggregate:String="(bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang.over),
(bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang)";bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang;resource.bundle.base.name="content.Language";
service.ranking:Long="2";\
servlet.context.name=
```

and then create module portlet "PortalWorkflowWeb" using new language module above:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.portal.workflow.web",
                "servlet.context.name=portal-workflow-web"
        }
    )
public class MyCustomLanguages implements ResourceBundleLoader {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle loadResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bundle1.loadResourceBundle(locale);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private AggregateResourceBundleLoader bundle1;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Reference(target = "(bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang.over)")
        public void setResourceBundleLoader(ResourceBundleLoader resourceBundleLoader) {
        bundle1 = new AggregateResourceBundleLoader(new CacheResourceBundleLoader(new 
                ClassResourceBundleLoader("content.Language", MyCustomLanguages.class.getClassLoader())), resourceBundleLoader);
    }
}
```

also write command to .bnd file of PortalWorkflowWeb module:

```
Bundle-Name: PortalWorkflowWeb
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.liferay.portal.workflow.web.override
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0

-liferay-aggregate-resource-bundles: \
    com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang.over

Web-ContextPath: /portal-workflow-web

-sources: true
-jsp: *.jsp,*.jspf
-plugin.bundle: com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.jsp: com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.sass: com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin
-sass: *
```

when i deploy to liferay server, they are unchanged like other language modules I have overridden.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: sorry, when i post image, i receive notification is "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: your edit is fine. Even with the reputation: Continue to post textual content as text, with formatting. Not as image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your bundle doesn't deploy, because its dependencies are not met. You specify

```
@Reference(target = "(bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang.over)")
```

and I'm not sure that `...lang.over` is a valid bundle's symbolic name. Where did you get this from? You'd have to specify the bundle you'd like to override there. (most likely - in the past there were two ways to override language keys, depending on their origin: in core or a module. I'm not 100% sure about the actual way to override in this place from the top of my head)

Edit: Now I see where that ...over comes from: It's your own bundle's name. Looking at Liferay's [blade samples for 7.3](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.3/liferay-workspace/overrides/login-web-resource-bundle-override), it looks like you don't need any Java code for overriding a module's resources

bnd.bnd from there:

```
Bundle-Description: Conveys the recommended approach to override com.liferay.login.web language keys file.
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.liferay.blade.login.web.resource.bundle.override
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Import-Package: *; version="${range;[=,+)}"
Provide-Capability:\
    liferay.resource.bundle;\
        resource.bundle.base.name="content.Language",\
    liferay.resource.bundle;\
        bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.login.web;\
        resource.bundle.aggregate:String="(bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.blade.login.web.resource.bundle.override),(bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.login.web)";\
        resource.bundle.base.name="content.Language";\
        service.ranking:Long="2";\
        servlet.context.name=login-web
-sources: true
```

Java code for overriding a module's resource files was last documented in the [7.0 blade samples](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.0/liferay-workspace/overrides/resource-bundle-override), since then it's configuration only.

And, not to forget: Contrary to usual expectations, your language resource files should be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: ...lang.over module is created to override old module language com.liferay.portal.workflow.lang, because i am using shared language key.